# How to remove a directory on pip uninstall/upgrade

Tags: python, pip, python-3.10

I'm developing a Python app which maintains a local repository through a number a CLI commands. This application has a settings file written in a certain directory. This file could change for newer versions of the application.

What I thought about is deleting this settings file on executing pip uninstall or upgrade. It isn't appropriate to delete it after each command, since I want to maintain its configuration between commands, i.e. as long as the user have a certain version installed.

As I say, my idea is to delete this settings file whenever the user executes a pip uninstall, also leaving the directory clean. If the user does an upgrade instead, it should be removed too, since the new settings file for the latest version would be created after by the app code when executing the first command.

Is there any way of adding some lines of code when performing a pip uninstall or pip upgrade? What would be the proper way of dealing with this otherwise?

I also thought about writing the version in the same settings file, and updating it in case it is necessary because it detects that the current version is a newer one. But I think it should be easier than this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pre-uninstall+script

Comment: Short answer: there is no way.

Comment: if the settings file is in a data directory included with the package it should automagically be removed i think(although im not 100% sure and i dont have the bandwidth to test it myself) .... if you are generating it somewhere else on first use it probably would not be possible